# How to interpet the EFL in OllyDbg?

Tags: debugging, assembly, ollydbg

What is and how to interpret the EFL under *registers* using OllyDbg?

What is `NO`, `NB`, `E`, `NE`, `BE`, `A`, `NS` ,`PO`, `GE`, `G`, …

Example:

```
EFL 00000246 (NO,NB,E,BE,NS,PE,GE,LE)
```

My futile decipher:

```
00000246 => 0000 ... 0010 0100 0110
NO   NB   E    BE   NS   PE   GE   LE
 0    0   0     0    0    1    1    1 <- I do not know if this is correct. 
                                         (Likely not.)
```

Operation:

```
AND ESI,7FFFFFFF
```

Result:

```
EFL 00000202 (NO,NB,NE,A,NS,PO,GE,G)
```

My ASCII, (inspired [by](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt)):

```
            _---------------------------=>  E -> NE
           /     _----------------------=> BE -> A
          |     /          _------------=> PE -> PO
          |    |          /          _--=> LE -> G
          |    |         |          /
          |    |         |         |
NO   NB   NE   A    NS   PO   GE   G
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0100 0110
0    0    0    0    0    1    1    1
```

---

*Help* has the following to say:

> Following EFL are the suffixes of conditional commands that satisfy
>   current flags. If, for example, you see:
>
> EFL 00000A86 (O,NB,NE,A,S,PE,GE,G),
>
> this means that JO and JNE will be taken whereas JB and JPO not.

---

I suspected [CPU Flags](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon2000/Debugging/Debugging.htm#CPUFlags), [FLAGS register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register), etc. but cant recognize e.g. `NO` in any of those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EFL` is the [FLAGS](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#EFLAGS_Register) register (expanded to include `EFLAGS`), used among other things to indicate parity, overflow/carry,  direction and branch flow as well as various CPU modes.

Olly slightly expands the register by separating out the booleans for common control status bits above EFL (the singular bits named 'C P A Z S T D O').

The abbreviations in brackets next to EFL's value the correlate to what can/cannot pass under the current EFLAGS, ie: NO stands for No-Overflow, toggling the OF bit will switch it to O for overflow.

Comment: Thanks. Yes thought it might have something to do with EFLAGS, but then what does e.g. `NO` interpreted as in regard to those? Is it a combination of `OF` and `NT`? How does the hex value relate? Is it perhaps a bitmap instead of a AND value?

Comment: @Zimzalabim: its a shorthand for the current state of the bit (so you don't need to do a bitwise breakdown of the EFLAGS value to guage its current state), updated my answer to include an example of this.

Comment: Good. Yes, my intuition first said `N` negated some `FLAG` value, but then what about e.g. `PE`? Is there a list that show what the abbreviations mean?

Comment: @Zimzalabim: I've never seen a list, but you don't really need one, rather just look at the bits required to change the value. PE is Parity Even, PO is Parity Odd.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. It is clearer now. I'm mostly on Linux. The range of tools on Windows is to envy. Though Linux usually with dbg is another world. Really wan tot buy IDA Pro but have to consider the cash – and level of use ;) OllyDbg is really powerful as well.

Comment: @Zimzalabim: there is an older version of of IDA which is free, though I have no clue if it works under linux.